# Setting emails to be sent at a specific times using Transactional Emails?

Tags: magento-enterprise, email, transactional

Is it possible to set up an email process, using the Transactional Email system, so that the system will send out follow up emails at specific times? I've already set it up so that when the order is placed, a follow up email is sent providing the customer with their order number. I would like to add a couple more emails to follow up after that such as "your order has been processed" or another one providing a coupon thanking them for ordering through us and so forth. There are probably solutions to this by coding it but I wanted to save some time and see if it can be created through the Admin side.

Hopefully this will help clear it up a little further in case my write up didn't make sense:

"You placed an order through the site, about 5 mins later you will receive the order confirmation with your order number. Then, about 3 days later you would receive another email notifying you that your order has been shipped with the providing tracking number. Around 10 hours later you'll receive another email with a coupon provided inside showing thanks for making the purchase."

Ideally that's how I would like the system to process it out as.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without a custom module as far as I know. There are some follow up extensions at the Magento connect in the "E-mail marketing" category that allows you to add extra emails to be mailed based on the order status and period specified.

Comment: This is correct. You'll need to write an extension or try one of the many email extensions available from Magento's store.